# Why don't children under the age of two need to be cremated?

Tags: rituals, cremation, agni-purana

Per the Agni Purana,

> [[158.9](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-agni-purana/d/doc1083388.html)] If a child dies when two years old no cremation needs to be done. It should be buried in the ground.

Why is that? What happens to the soul of the baby if it's not cremated?

Comment: Just curious to know why does it matter to you?

Comment: @Rāmachandra - A couple years ago, one of my older cousin's children died (age ~1.5), and they cremated her even though a guru told them to bury her. So, I was wondering why the guru said that and I found the Agni Purana line, but I still didn't understand why the baby's age mattered.

Comment: Sorry to here that Sir.Quite a valid Qn.